# Como extrair números preservando sua formatação de uma string em PHP?

Tags: php

estou com uma dúvida, como eu posso fazer para extrair números de uma String em PHP preservando a formatação do mesmo?

Encontrei uma solução no fórum em inglês, porém ao extrair os números o padrão da data, por exemplo, não é preservado.

```
$str = 'Paga. ref. a nota fiscal número 8888, com o cheque número 9999 em 14/08/2015';
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Fonte: [Extract numbers from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6278312/5227226)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$re = "/([0-9\\/])/"; 
$str = "Paga. ref. a nota fiscal número 8888, com o cheque número 9999 em 14/08/2015"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Veja no Regex. https://regex101.com/r/tV7eY9/1

### Explicando

`0-9` - Dentro da *string* quero apenas números.

`\` - Barra de escape, senão o comando vai dar erro quando colocar a barra da data.

`/` - Além dos números, quero que também seja selecionado a barra. Mas pode ser:

`-` traço

`_` underscore

`.` pontos

Comment: Muito obrigado, era esta mesmo a solução que procurava!

Comment: Isso, eu tinha editado colocando essa observações no próprio código. Ótimo, serve para futuros dúvidas de usuários, pois verifiquei que não tinha nada semelhante no fórum para `PHP`